# Is the Language L := {a^nb^nc^n | n >= 1} in P?

Tags: complexity-theory

**L := {a^nb^nc^n | n >= 1}** is not regular (Cannot be pumped).

Yet i can easily find a 4-Tape deterministic Turing Machine that accepts L in polytime.

Therefor L should be in P right?

Comment: Yes; why do you think it might not be recognizable in polynomial time?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 4-tape deterministic TM that accepts L in polytime, then L is in P. The reason is that you can simulate a 4-tape TM using a single-tape TM by increasing the runtime by at most a polynomial factor. The product of polynomials is a polynomial, and you have your answer. Proving this might be daunting, if you are called upon to do it e.g. in the context of an examination; but it is definitely not too hard to show this is the case.

A simpler proof might not rely on 4-tape TMs but directly write down a single-tape TM for this problem. Then no proof is needed (except that your TM works, of course). A strategy might be this:

1. ensure that the input tape begins with a^n b^n
2. ensure that the input tape ends with b^n c^n
3. halt-accept if both are true, reject otherwise

If we can do steps 1 and 2 each in polynomial time, then the overall problem is in P. Note these problems are very similar; let's consider how we'd solve the first one:

1. make sure we start with a (since n >= 1)
2. change a to A and then scan until we find the first b; if no more b, halt-reject
3. change b to B and go back until we find the last A
4. move right; then

   - if another a, repeat from step 2
   - if B, scan right and ensure there are no more b; if there are, halt-reject, otherwise halt-accept

This TM moves back and forth across half the string, crossing out pairs of a and b as it goes. It does this exactly as many times as there are instances of a in the worst case (when the string is a^n b^n). Since (n/2) * (n/2) = n^2/4, the runtime is polynomial.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer. Yep the 4-tape was my idea it just made it a bit easier to think about it. And since (like you mentioned) k-tape TM's can be simulated down to a 1-Tape TM it doesnt matter.